# Docker permission issue after copying files

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, file-permissions

I have the following docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

#Install Node
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs-legacy -y
RUN apt-get install npm -y
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10



# Create app directory 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# COPY distribution
COPY dist dist
COPY package.json package.json

# Substitute dependencies from environment variables
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

And here is the entrypoint script

```
#!/bin/sh
cp package.json /usr/src/app/dist/
cd /usr/src/app/dist/
echo "starting server"
exec npm start
```

When I run the image it fails with this error

```
sh: 1: http-server: not found
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
```

I tried various kinds of installation but still get the same error, I also tried checking if the node_modules conatins the http-server executable and it does. I tried forcing 777 permission on all the files but still running into the same error

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing an `npm install` call somewhere, so the `node_modules` directory, nor any of its contents (like `http-server`) are present on the image. After the `COPY package.json package.json`, if you add a `RUN npm install` line, that might be all you need.

There are a few other things that could be simpler too though, like you probably don't need an `ENTRYPOINT` script to run the app and copy `package.json` since that's already done. Here's a simplified version of a Node Docker image I've been running with. I'm using the [base Node images](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) which, I believe, are Linux-based, but you could probably keep the Ubuntu stuff if you wanted to and it shouldn't be an issue.

```
FROM node:6.9.5

# Create non-root user to run app with

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/bash my-app

# Set working directory

WORKDIR /home/my-app

COPY package.json ./

# Change user so that everything that's npm-installed belongs to it

USER my-app

# Install dependencies

RUN npm install --no-optional && npm cache clean

# Switch to root and copy over the rest of our code
# This is here, after the npm install, so that code changes don't trigger an un-caching
# of the npm install line

USER root
COPY .eslintrc index.js ./
COPY app ./app
RUN chown -R my-app:my-app /home/my-app
USER my-app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

It's good practice to make a specific user for owning/running your code and not using root, but, as I understand it, you need to use root to put files onto your image, hence the switching users a couple times here (which is what `USER ...` does).

I'll also note that I use this image with Docker Compose for local development, which is what the comment about code changes is referring to.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the entrypoint script actually does more, but I removed the content for simplicity. I am copying the dist folder thats created after the project builds. So it should contain the node_modules. I also verified that the http-server is present in the node modules by listing contents in the entrypoint script

Comment: Also I tried running npm install in the dokcerfile but still see teh same error

Comment: Can it be that its a path issue?

Comment: @user_mda So `node_modules` in inside of `dist/`? You might try changing the `WORKDIR`: `WORKDIR /usr/src/app/dist`.

Comment: So i had to change permissions on the entire dist folder chown -R root:root  fixed it